# Separate List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer)) to get two List(Of String) matching/not predicate

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I need to separate a `List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer))` to get two `List's(Of String)`. If the `String` matching some function `ValidateFormat`(returns `Boolean`), then I need it in "`match`" List, if not - in "`notMatch`" List.

I can use `Where` extension method twice to get two List's(Of Tuple, Integer):

```
    Dim initial As List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer))
    '...initial List filled..'
    Dim match As List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer)) = _
    initial.Where(Function(x) ValidateFormat(x.Item1)).ToList
    Dim notMatch As List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer)) = _
    initial.Where(Function(x) Not ValidateFormat(x.Item1)).ToList
```

But I need just Lists of `String`, not `Tuple`. Is there an effective way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Add `.Select(Function(c) c.Item1)` between `Where` and `ToList` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like:

```
var lookups = initial.ToLookup(x => ValidateFormat(x.Item1), x => x.Item2);
var match = lookups[true].ToList();
var notMatch = lookups[false].ToList();
```

That checks each item once, splitting the collection into groups of "matching" or "not matching" - and the second argument to `ToLookup` says how to convert each original element into a value in the lookup for the specific key (the true/false in this case).

You *could* use `Where` and `Select` of course - this just feels cleaner to me.

Comment: +1, not only it is cleaner, but also would iterate over the `initial` only once, as to be compared to using `Where` to populate  `match` and `notMatch`.